# Magento greek characters as html entities

Tags: html, magento, editor, wysiwyg

I'm building a Magento site and there is an issue with the WYSIWYG editor and Greek characters, they appear as html entities.

If I write:

```
Ευχαριστούμε
```

I get:
`<p>&Epsilon;&upsilon;&chi;&alpha;&rho;&iota;&sigma;&tau;&omicron;ύ&mu;&epsilon;</p>`

Instead of:

```
<p>Ευχαριστούμε</p>
```

Is there some way I can fix this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my memory serves me correct, I remember doing this some time ago for chinese symbols. I did a little research and it still appears to be valid so I supplied my code.

The configuraion file for TinyMCE is located here: `[Magentorootdir]/js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js`  And adding the following line `entity_encoding : "raw"` as seen below

> ```
>     var settings = {
>         schema : 'html5',
>         entity_encoding : "raw",//New Line
>         mode : (mode != undefined ? mode : 'none'),
>         elements : this.id,
>         theme : 'advanced',
>         plugins : plugins,
>         theme_advanced_buttons1 : magentoPlugins + 'magentowidget,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect',
>         theme_advanced_buttons2 : 'cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,forecolor,backcolor',
>         theme_advanced_buttons3 : 'tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,iespell,media,advhr,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen',
>         theme_advanced_buttons4 : 'insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,pagebreak',
>         theme_advanced_toolbar_location : 'top',
>         theme_advanced_toolbar_align : 'left',
>         theme_advanced_statusbar_location : 'bottom',
>         theme_advanced_resizing : true,
>         convert_urls : false,
>         relative_urls : false,
>         content_css: this.config.content_css,
>         custom_popup_css: this.config.popup_css,
>         magentowidget_url: this.config.widget_window_url,
>         magentoPluginsOptions: magentoPluginsOptions,
>         doctype : '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">',
> ```

Documentation found here: 
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:entity_encoding

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Please note that you need a comma in the end as well entity_encoding : "raw", //New Line

Comment: Yea I had to test and when I made the comment in here I accidentally deleted it.  Sorry about that.  Updated the post

Comment: Also keep in mind, this will be deleted on upgrade however, I think there is a way to do this modification in a module. I'm not a fan of editing core type files but maybe another dev can shine light on this.